# Magento product imports from csv file

Tags: php4

I want to import Magento products from my csv file, but when I import this csv file I get an error like this ( Skip import row, required field "sku" not defined) However, I had this field defined in my csv file.

If any one has any idea about that then please advise me. Which method should I follow to import my csv products to Magento

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution its very simple:

1. just go to system->import/export and then u export all product by csv
2. now enter all other fields or attribute data in csv which u required.
3. ```
   <?php
   set_time_limit(0);
   define('MAGENTO_MAGE_LOCATION','/your site name path/app/Mage.php');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $handle = fopen("your csv name path.csv", "r");
   $count=0;
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE)
   {
     $count++;
     if($data[0] != 'store')
     {
       require_once MAGENTO_MAGE_LOCATION;
       Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
       $product->setSku($data[5]);
       $product->setName($data[7]);
        .
        .
        .
       try {
         $product->save();
         echo '<br> hi product save successfully in magento uniqe mobile store';
       }
       catch (Exception $ex) {  
         echo 'Handle the error';
       }

     }// end of if statment store 
   }// end of while loop 
   fclose($handle);
   ?>
   ```

use this code and set all products but all fields set acourding to ur CSV file. then run this code . 
its working i test this code. its my own creation

Comment: i find this solution after lots of search in and work on it . i import my csv product through this code .